# On a JSON - REST API how to perform warnings on non-critical errors or re-attempts

Tags: json, rest, api

*[I mention the sources I've looked at below]*

I am designing an API and I found over and over again that warnings would be helpful, these were the 3 most common use cases:

1. To convey that a non-critical issue occurred when doing a POST:
   (For example, data not matching some validation was ignored and the
   resource was created anyway)
2. To convey that a side-effect occurred: (For example, an associated resource that was valid yesterday, is now expired and was removed - the main resource however is still valid)
3. To convey that an action was already performed: (For example, when POSTing payment data on an item that has already been paid for)

In all 3 instances the response to the verb is succesful, the relevant response is giving back the resource (in case 1 the resource was created, in case 2 the resource is still there, in case 3 the resource is now paid for)

In all 3 instances I feel like I should be informing the Client but I could not find the standard way of doing this.

Adding the response as part of the body would require me changing the resource model, which is something I'd rather avoid

A standarized "_warnings" key that is not part of the model per se is something I'm partial about (but I haven't seen implementations of it)

Ideally, I feel the information should be part of the headers, but the only similar approach I found was the Warnings headers which is deprecated (see below).

**Things I've looked at:**

**Previous (relevant) question:** https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/315556/warnings-in-a-rest-api-as-not-critical-errors

**Reason why is not 100% relevant:** The question is focusing on the appropriate status code, and weather it should be doing warnings at all as opposed to focusing on the resources themselves and where to put the body

**Standard warning header:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Warning

**Reason why is not relevant** Header has behaviour associated with it (caches), and is on the verge of changing (has been deprecated)

Comment: if you don't want to add it to the response body (like make it part of the json) then the other alternative is to add it as HTTP headers... something like `X-api-warnings: blah blah`  maybe?  (be aware that HTTP headers have a quite limited legal charset, there's no newlines and only ascii characters iirc. a way to get around that is to have your headers base64 encoded, eg `X-api-warning: (base64 of the real warning)` )

Comment: Custom headers sound like an anti-pattern, but breaking the representation of the resource also sounds like an anti pattern.